# how to display the rendered data correctly in their respective columns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am having trouble displaying the `arr` dummy API into columns similar to the below image, where each column has a header followed by their children, but however, I am getting everything inside the first column when it should be `parent > child`

layout data rendering

[image: layout]

I am getting the following UI

[image: error]

```
const arr = [
  {
      "demo": [
          {
              "_id": "xx122",
              "name": "Historian",
              "tags": [
                  "demo"
              ],
              "things": [],
              "list": [],
              "queries": [],
              "notes": []
          }
      ],
      "demo_2": [
        {
            "_id": "xx123",
            "name": "Demo",
            "tags": [
                "demo_2"
            ],
            "things": [],
            "list": [],
            "queries": [],
            "notes": []
        }
    ],
  }
]


  const modArray = Object.keys(arr[0]).map(i => {
    return {id: i, ...arr[0][i]}
  });
    
  export default function Demo() {
    return (
        <div>
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {modArray.map((i) => (
                            <th key={i.id}>{i.id}</th>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {modArray.map((items, index) => {
                        console.log(items.id);

                        return (
                            <tr key={items.id}>
                                {Object.keys(items).map((key) => {
                                    console.log(items[key]._id);
                                    return <td key={items[key]._id}>{items[key]._id}</td>;
                                })}
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are returning a row for each item in the array, rather than a column. It should look just like the head. Here's an example of the pattern.

```
<tr> // wrapper row
  {modArray.map((items) => {
    return (
      <td key={items.id}>
        <table>
          <tr>{/* keys map logic goes here */}</tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    )
  })}
</tr>
```

Comment: I tried your example , but I always got `<tr> cannot appear as a child of <td>.
    at tr`, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I just updated the example to wrap it in a table to get rid. of that warning. Turns out React needs to actually nest it inside of a new table element.

Comment: If you can switch to `<div>` tags with flexbox instead of a table, you will be able to have better control over nesting and CSS control.